# Combine two futures as main and backup

Tags: java, completable-future

I have two processes which should start in parallel and if the first process fails, I should use second process result. I came up with the following code. Is there any sensible way to simplify it?

```
final CompletableFuture<Data> mainFut = mainProcess(...);
final CompletableFuture<Data> backupFut = backupProcess(...);
final CompletableFuture<Data> resultFut = new CompletableFuture<>();
mainFut.handle((r, t) -> {
    if (t == null) {
        resultFut.complete(r); // main process is fine, use its result
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Main process failed, using backup", t);
        backupFut.handle((rb, tb) -> {
            if (tb == null) {
                resultFut.complete(rb); //backup is fine, use its result
            } else {
                resultFut.completeExceptionally(tb); //backup failed too
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
    return null;
});
return resultFut;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the result of `handle`, which would be perfect for your use case, e.g.

```java
final CompletableFuture<Data> mainFut = mainProcess(...);
final CompletableFuture<Data> backupFut = backupProcess(...);

return mainFut.handle((r,t) -> t == null? r: backupFut.join());
```

If you want to avoid the potentially blocking `join()` call, you can use

```java
final CompletableFuture<Data> mainFut = mainProcess(...);
final CompletableFuture<Data> backupFut = backupProcess(...);

return mainFut.handle((r1, t1) -> t1 == null? mainFut: backupFut)
    .thenCompose(Function.identity());
```

The backup operation’s result will supersede the main operation’s exception, but when both fail, you can include the original exception in the exceptional result like

```java
return mainFut.handle((r1, t1) -> t1 == null? mainFut:
        backupFut.whenComplete((r2, t2) -> { if(t2 != null) t2.addSuppressed(t1); }))
    .thenCompose(Function.identity());
```

Comment: Nice. `.thenCompose(Function.identity())` seems the trick I've struggled to invent. The only thing I don't like about your solution, it's that main's exception will be lost if backup succeed. I had `LOGGER.error` for that. So seems need to use `if` anyway, could not use `?`.

Comment: @kan, there is a variant of `.thenCompose` that works on a failed future: `.exceptionallyCompose`. See my full answer below.

Comment: You could implement the logging independently, e.g. using `final CompletableFuture<Data> mainFut = mainProcess(...) .whenComplete((r, t) -> { if(t != null) LOGGER.error("Main process failed, using backup", t); });`, without affecting the subsequent logic.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CompletableFuture#exceptionallyCompose`, this becomes basically a one liner:

```
var resultFut = mainFut.exceptionallyCompose(throwable -> backupFut);
```

**Edit:** `exceptionallyCompose` is available since Java 12.

Comment: Nice. Seems it's available since Java 12 though.

Comment: Worth noting that this has been added in Java 12.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this code would match your coding style but would something like this work to reduce indentation levels and try and avoid nesting hell?

```
mainFut.handle((r, t) -> {
    if (t == null) {
        resultFut.complete(r); // main process is fine, use its result
        return null;
    }

    LOGGER.error("Main process failed, using backup", t);
    backupFut.handle((rb, tb) -> {
        if (tb == null) {
            resultFut.complete(rb); //backup is fine, use its result
            return null;
        }
        
        resultFut.completeExceptionally(tb); //backup failed too
        return null;
    });
    return null;
});
```

Also just a thought I'm not 100% familiar with lambda functions do you need to return values in those lambda functions? You could remove the last two return statements if not.

Comment: Not sure if it looks simpler... maybe even worse as you have more meaningless return statements. Yes, the return is technically unused, but mandatory as the `handle` requires it.